# Pipe Code to sh — Script not waiting on read Command

Tags: shell, curl, download, pipe, posix

**Content of my remote file:**

```
#!/bin/sh
read foo && echo "$foo"
```

**What I’m doing locally in my terminal:**

```
$ curl -fLSs http://example.com/my-remote-file.sh | sh
```

**What I’m expecting:**

The downloaded script should prompt the user to enter something and wait for the users input.

**What actually happens:**

The downloaded script skips the `read` command and continues executing.

**Question**:

How can I prompt the user to input something from a script that is downloaded via `curl`? I know that `sh <(curl -fLSs http://example.com/my-remote-file.sh)` is working, but this is not POSIX compliant and I’d like to achieve that.

Comment: Try putting a shebang as the first line of your remote file... `#!/bin/bash` or similar.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: There is of course a shebang in my remote file. But I'll add it to my code snippet to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *stdin* is reading from `curl`, rather than the keyboard. You need to change your script to instruct it to read specifically from the terminal, like this:

```
read input < /dev/tty
echo $input
```

Comment: Actually this is not answering my question as I don’t wanted to use `bash`.

Comment: I had another think about this... please have another look.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'll check this out later today.